# Реализация хранения личных сообщений и бесед на mysql

Tags: mysql, хранение-данных

У меня есть два варианта хранения данных:

---

1. Хранить каждый диалог в отдельной таблице, таким образом, чтобы каждый читал информацию из своей таблице. Это решает проблему, когда один собеседник удаляет сообщение, а другой хочет оставить себе. И при добавлении нового участника в беседу, история сообщений для него была бы пуста.
2. Держать все в одной таблице и использовать партиции. Плюсы и минусы двух подходов? Ваш вариант?
3. а что делать, если один из пользователей удалил беседу целиком?

Comment: А партиции то зачем ? они нужны когда ооочень много данных и надо распределять их на разные физические диски для ускорения работы. И да, первый способ никуда не годится. с отдельными таблицами работать дико не удобно. таблицы в реляционных БД должны создаваться только во время проектирования системы, но не на ходу во время ее работы

Comment: таблица одна. раз сообщения личные значит их должны видеть всего 2 человека отправитель и получатель. Значит достаточно ввести дополнительное поле/поля "признак удаления". Если один из коворящих удаляет сообщение, то мы только помечаем что оно для него удалено и показывать не надо. при этом сообщение остается в БД и другой человек его сможет видеть

Comment: Плюс беседа еще, правил вопрос

Comment: А что беседа ?. вы храните в БД идентификатор беседы, и предположим еще одна таблица с беседами, где указываются ее участники. вот и все

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Во первых, прочитайте про нормализацию базы данных, если Вы делаете это на реляционной базе, то **забудьте про создание отдельных таблиц** для хранения одинаковых данных. Одинаковые данные должны храниться в одной таблице.

Проблему, про то что у Вас один собеседник удаляет сообщение, а другой оставляет себе решается тем, что записи необязательно удалять из БД, а достаточно проставить флаг, что пользователь удалил сообщение. А насчет партицированния таблицы или шардинга по серверам, оно Вам пригодиться на миллионах записей, поэтому не скоро.

Структура, при условии создания этого в реляционной структуре, у Вас должна быть примерно следующая, попытался описать быстро, поэтому извиняюсь, если что-то не учел в вашей архитектуре:

1. **Таблица для хранения общей информации по диалогу**.

   - id INT
   - name VARCHAR(50)
   - created TIMESTAMP
2. **Таблица для хранения сообщений диалога** - здесь будут храниться все сообщения привязанные к диалогу.

   - id INT
   - dialog_id INT
   - text TEXT
   - created TIMESTAMP
3. **Таблица участников диалога**

   - dialog_id INT
   - user_id INT
   - joined TIMESTAMP (указывает, когда участник присоединился к диалогу, чтобы не показывать сообщения, которые были до того, как он присоединился, возможно заменить данное поле на смещение по Id, чтобы это работало быстрее)
4. **Таблица скрытых (удаленных) сообщений**

   - message_id INT
   - user_id INT

Comment: Может тогда стоит посмотреть на noSql, например key-value, хранилище? Если да, то какая бд подойдет?

Comment: На небольших обьемах данных NoSQL Вам не даст ощутимого прироста в производительности и его чаще всего используют для структуры которая неоднозначна. Если же Вы хотите познать что-то  про хранение данных в noSQL начните с MongoDB, а дальше исследуйте какая база будет удобнее для Вас.

Comment: А как хранит данные о переписках ВКонтакте например?
Слышал, что они как раз таки используют разные таблицы для хранения? Правда у них вроде бы там своя субд

Comment: @Mike, есть минусы например у денормализации данных?
Просто все равно стоит вопрос между двумя выборами хранения данных, только второй уже который Вы порекомендовали.

Comment: @МишаЛандау Денормализация требует больше места на дисках. Очень сложно поддерживаются обновления (одну запись в НФ проще обновить, чем возможно сотни денормализованных). Вы представьте 100 чел в диалоге. по вашему первому варианту вам надо будет каждое сообщение записать 100 раз. это как минимум дикие тормоза при записи.

Comment: @МишаЛандау Сначала строят НФ данные. потом, когда в результате эксплуатации вы наберете десятки миллионов записей вы задумаетесь сначала об оптимизации запросов (тут большое поле для деятельности). когда этого станет недостаточно вы наконец увидите узкие места и подуете как было бы удобно для вас делить данные на пул серверов и вот тогда возможно понадобится задуматься о денормализации

Comment: @Mike, спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

> Хранить каждый диалог в отдельной таблице

Это вообще не вариант, на мой взгляд. Не сможете получить сообщения, отправленные определённым пользователем. Да и 100500 таблиц это же не удобно, не понятно какие из них активные какие нет.

Если сообщений не огромное количество, то подойдёт простая структура mysql-таблицы:

```
CREATE TABLE `messages` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_sender` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `id_recipient` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `added_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `message` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `filter` (`id_sender`,`id_recipient`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

и другие необходимые поля по необходимости. Дата редактирования, прочитано ли сообщение и т.д.